# Webpack, babel, react, react-transform-hmr, not sure where the issue is

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have many moving pieces and I'm trying to figure out how to resolve this problem:

> Uncaught Error: locals[0] does not appear to be a `module` object with Hot Module replacement API enabled. You should disable react-transform-hmr in production by using `env` section in Babel configuration. See the example in README: https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-hmr

What I'm doing is packaging [react-toolbox](http://react-toolbox.com/#/) for [cljsjs](http://cljsjs.github.io/) which requires using webpack to compile react-toolbox into a JavaScript (5) file that can then be used from ClojureScript. I think around this step is where I have to find the solution. My webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var entryName = "react-toolbox.inc";

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "components", "index.js"),

    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },

    output: {
        filename: entryName + ".js",
        libraryTarget: "var",
        library: "ReactToolbox"
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /(\.js|\.jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "babel",
                query: {presets: ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]}
            },
            {
                test: /(\.scss|\.css)$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss!sass")
            }
        ]
    },

    postcss: [autoprefixer],

    node: {
        fs: 'empty'
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin(entryName + '.css', {allChunks: true})
    ]
};
```

What I found online is something about setting NODE_ENV to production in .babelrc, but I cannot expect environmental modifications to be able to get this package compiled, so, whatever solution I apply, it has to be through this file or [the others in the package](https://github.com/pupeno/packages/tree/react-toolbox/react-toolbox).

I am successfully using this library in my application by including directly (without packaging in cljsjs) with the following webpack config:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        "./src/app_js/webpack.js"
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "www", "app"),
        filename: "js_dependencies.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".scss", ".css", ".js", ".json"],
        modulesDirectories: [
            "node_modules",
            path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules")
        ]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /(\.js|\.jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "babel",
                query: { presets: ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"] }
            }, {
                test: /(\.scss|\.css)$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss!sass")
            }
        ]
    },
    postcss: [autoprefixer],
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("js_dependencies.css", { allChunks: true }),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(), // https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#occurrenceorderplugin
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(), // Don't emit compiled assets when there's an error.
    ]
};
```